# Flink checkpoint status is always in progress

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use datastream connector KafkaSource and HbaseSinkFunction, consume data from kafka and write it to hbase.

I enable the checkpoint like this：
`env.enableCheckpointing(3000,CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);`

The data in kafka has already be successfully written to hbase，but checkpoints status on ui page is still “in progress” and has not changed.

Why does this happen and how to deal with it？

Flink version：1.13.3,
Hbase version：1.3.1,
Kafka version：0.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can post the complete checkpoint configuration parameters.

In addition, you can adjust the checkpoint interval and observe it.

The current checkpoint interval is 3s, which is relatively short.